# Angular Nested array form builder stuck when adding sub items

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder

I am trying to create form builder using Angular succeeded for the direct items. I followed the [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-formarray-dynamic-forms?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Here they are adding new skills by 'Add Skill' button and they are adding it dynamically.

But my requirement is that I have sub-skills array like below and that needs to be added dynamically as a default items. Anything extra needed to be added by buttons.

```
const subSkills = [
  { label: 'Angular', value: 'Angular' },
  { label: 'React', value: 'React' },
  { label: 'VueJs', value: 'VueJs' },
]
```

I have added something like below to add some default value.

But i got below error.
ERROR
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

```
newEmployee(empId): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      skills: this.addEmployeeSkill(empId)
    });
  }

  addEmployee() {
    this.employees().push(this.newEmployee(0));
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `addEmployeeSkill` does not return an array, but `skills` property requires a `FormBuilder` array